# Creating excel report from mysql database using phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, pdo

I have a sql query that displays records of attendance per employee so what I want now is generate an excel report from it but I don't really understand how does phpexcel works and I also used in drag and drop reporting tools like crystal reports. Could someone help to make it in phpexcel. Here's my complete code from mysql database:

```
try{
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$con->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
exit();
}
//print first employee table
try{
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM emptb WHERE Department = :dept AND  SectionName = :section AND LineName = :line ORDER BY id ASC");
$query->bindParam(':dept',$dept);
$query->bindParam(':section',$section);
$query->bindParam(':line',$line);
$query->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
exit();
}
while($row = $query->fetch())
{
echo <<<_END
ID: <input type='text' value='$row[EmpID]' readonly='readonly'/> Employee:  <input type='text' value='$row[Lastname], $row[Firstname]' readonly='readonly'/> <p/>
Section: <input type='text' value='$row[SectionName]' readonly='readonly'/>  Line: <input type='text' value='$row[LineName]' readonly='readonly'/><p/>
_END;

try{
$qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE EmpID = :id AND  ValidDate BETWEEN DATE('2015-08-01') AND DATE('2015-08-30') GROUP BY ValidDate  ORDER BY ValidDate ASC");
$qry->bindParam(':id',$row['EmpID']);
$qry->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
exit();
}
echo "<table>";
while($subrow = $qry->fetch())
{
echo <<<_END
<tr>
<td>$subrow[ValidDate]</td>
<td>$subrow[TimeIn]</td>
<td>$subrow[LunchOut]</td>
<td>$subrow[LunchIn]</td>
<td>$subrow[TimeOut]</td>
</tr>
_END;
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: How did you try to generate an excel file using phpexcel and what was the error message you received or the unexpected behaviour you encountered?

Comment: I didn't tried it yet but i know how to generate excel file but not using phpexcel and its only in tabular format.

Comment: Why not just create a CSV

Comment: It will not have any formatting and only phpexcel is applicable for that.

Comment: @NewbieN: You need to try first and if you encounter any issues, then we can help you along.

Comment: Can you give some sample code or tutorial for phpexcel and mysql....

Comment: I'd recommend starting by reading the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation), and looking at the [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples) provided.... they are there for a reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace

```
echo "<table>";
while($subrow = $qry->fetch())
{
    echo <<<_END
    <tr>
    <td>$subrow[ValidDate]</td>
    <td>$subrow[TimeIn]</td>
    <td>$subrow[LunchOut]</td>
    <td>$subrow[LunchIn]</td>
    <td>$subrow[TimeOut]</td>
    </tr>
_END;
}
echo "</table>";
```

with something like:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$row = 1;
while($subrow = $qry->fetch())
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $subrow['ValidDate']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $subrow['TimeIn']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $subrow['LunchOut']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $subrow['LunchIn']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $subrow['TimeOut']);
    $row++;
}
$excelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('myFileName.xlsx');
```

You'll probably need to play with it a bit to convert dates/times to MS Excel serialized timestamps, and apply format masks but that's the basics of creating an Excel file from a database query using PHPExcel

Answer (score 1):

**Create and download excel file or report using [phpExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)**

1. First of all download [excel-report.zip](http://www.techhunters.net/downloads/excel-report.zip) and extract it.
2. You will find index.php in root and one more folder.
3. Open index.php and take a look at the code.
4. Code itself is self descriptive and well commented.
5. You can add column heading and records.
6. You can also add color in particular cell or entire row.
7. If you want to set bold font for particular cell or row,it is also given in code.
8. Width of any column in excel file is adjustable.I have set it to auto adjust.